# Looping over Array of objects and returning random object value - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to loop over an array of objects and display a random quote from the data, so far my code returns *undefined*. Any idea's why?

Code so far..

```
const quotesToUse = [{
    quote: "This was the biggest quote ever - Array Object",
    author: "Derek Bullshido",
  },
  {
    quote: "Hey hows it going - Array Object",
    author: "Paul Frank",
  },
  {
    quote: "Why can I say that - Array Object",
    author: "Derek Paul",
  },
]

function randomQuotes() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 1; i += 1 )  {
    const randomQuote = quotesToUse[i][Math.floor(Math.random() * quotesToUse[i].quote.length)];
    document.getElementById("container").appendChild(text).append(randomQuote);
}
```

I am trying to display the quote (String) randomly.

Comment: quotesToUse[i].quote.length <-- makes no sense, why are you referencing the length of the string.

Comment: I gathered that... thats what I am asking

Comment: `for (var i = 0; i < 1; i += 1 ) `? That's the same as var i = 0;

Comment: you want to display you mean console.log? not very clear what you are trying to do

Comment: Shivraj - question updated

Comment: basically, ignoring how screwed up your loop is, what you really need to do is randomize i and then read that particular array element.  Currently you're at least using a randomizer, but it's inside that broken loop.  If you want to know how large that array is, it would be quotestouse.length, not quotestouse[i].quote.length, as that will return the length of a quote, not the lengh of the array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably want this to get the quote:

```
const randomQuote = quotesToUse[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotesToUse.length)].quote;
```

I don't know what you're trying to do with the loop.

Comment: Thats it, I am just experimenting as I am learning, so no loop needed. Thanks that worked.

Comment: Mark as answer appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

You can return random quotes with this function:

```js
const quotesToUse = [{
    quote: "This was the biggest quote ever - Array Object",
    author: "Derek Bullshido",
  },
  {
    quote: "Hey hows it going - Array Object",
    author: "Paul Frank",
  },
  {
    quote: "Why can I say that - Array Object",
    author: "Derek Paul",
  },
]

function randomQuotes() {
    const randomQuote = quotesToUse[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotesToUse.length)];
    const quote = document.createElement("DIV");
    quote.textContent=randomQuote.quote;
    const author = document.createElement("DIV");
    author.textContent=randomQuote.author;  document.getElementById("container").appendChild(quote).appendChild(author);
}

randomQuotes();
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this more readably with [rando.js](https://github.com/nastyox/Rando.js). Just don't forget to add the script tag to the head of your HTML document if you want to use this code.

```js
const quotesToUse = [
  {quote: "This was the biggest quote ever - Array Object", author: "Derek Bullshido"},
  {quote: "Hey hows it going - Array Object", author: "Paul Frank"},
  {quote: "Why can I say that - Array Object", author: "Derek Paul"},
];

var randomValueFromArray = rando(quotesToUse).value;
console.log(randomValueFromArray.quote);
```

```html
<script src="https://randojs.com/1.0.0.js"></script>
```